# Unexpected token `<`. in Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error, error-messages

I have the following trigger:

```
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> accs = [
        SELECT ShippingPostalCode, BillingPostalCode
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN Trigger.New
    ];
}
```

It produces the error:

> Unexpected token `<`.

I can not understand why. Help me, please.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with how you are looking to reference the `trigger.new` context.

The binding expression `:` must be used as follows.

```
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> accs = [
        SELECT ShippingPostalCode, BillingPostalCode
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New
    ];
}
```